# How to align properly the output of sed capture grous

Tags: sed, alignment, capture-group

I parse some files with logs, and I get specific values using capture groups in sed. It works, but the alignment is not proper when I have some big values

This is an example of a log:

`== 2022-02-01 18:30:36.301 +0100 == Packet received at ingress stage, tag 0, type ORDERED Packet info: len 131 port 18 interface 18 vsys 1 wqe index 31527 packet 0x0xc0046e99c0, HA: 0, IC: 0 Packet decoded dump: L2: 00:50:56:b8:17:29->00:50:56:b8:6f:d7, type 0x0800 IP: 172.16.10.20->172.16.0.10, protocol 6 version 4, ihl 5, tos 0x00, len 117, id 27949, frag_off 0x4000, ttl 128, checksum 5931(0x2b17) TCP: sport 21, dport 62040, seq 3281740227, ack 4101579101, reserved 0, offset 5, window 256, checksum 21106, flags 0x18 ( ACK PSH), urgent data 0, l4 data len 77 TCP option:`

And here is the output of my command:

```
sed -E 's/.*at ([a-z]+) stage.*tag ([0-9]+).*type ([A-Z]+) .*IP: ([0-9\.]+)->([0-9\.]+).*sport ([0-9]+).*dport ([0-9]+).*\( ([A-Z\ ]+)\).*data len ([0-9]+).*/\1 \t\2       \t\3   \t\4 -> \5  \t\t\6 \t-> \7    \t\8      \t\9/' one_liners2
slowpath        2900202469              ATOMIC          172.16.0.10 -> 172.16.10.20             62040   -> 21           SYN             0
fastpath        1068            ATOMIC          172.16.0.10 -> 172.16.10.20             62040   -> 21           SYN             0
ingress         0               ORDERED         172.16.10.20 -> 172.16.0.10             21      -> 62040        SYN ACK         0
fastpath        1068            ATOMIC          172.16.10.20 -> 172.16.0.10             21      -> 62040        SYN ACK         0
ingress         0               ORDERED         172.16.0.10 -> 172.16.10.20             62040   -> 21           ACK             0
fastpath        1068            ATOMIC          172.16.0.10 -> 172.16.10.20             62040   -> 21           ACK             0
ingress         0               ORDERED         172.16.10.20 -> 172.16.0.10             21      -> 62040        ACK PSH         77
```

As you can see above, the alignment for the first line is not good. I tried by using \t and spaces, but still the first row is displayed with bad alignment in comparison to the other lines. Is there any way for sed to align them in a neat way?

Desired output:

```
slowpath        2900202469      ATOMIC          172.16.0.10 -> 172.16.10.20             62040   -> 21           SYN             0
fastpath        1068            ATOMIC          172.16.0.10 -> 172.16.10.20             62040   -> 21           SYN             0
ingress         0               ORDERED         172.16.10.20 -> 172.16.0.10             21      -> 62040        SYN ACK         0
fastpath        1068            ATOMIC          172.16.10.20 -> 172.16.0.10             21      -> 62040        SYN ACK         0
ingress         0               ORDERED         172.16.0.10 -> 172.16.10.20             62040   -> 21           ACK             0
fastpath        1068            ATOMIC          172.16.0.10 -> 172.16.10.20             62040   -> 21           ACK             0
ingress         0               ORDERED         172.16.10.20 -> 172.16.0.10             21      -> 62040        ACK PSH         77
```

Is there maybe another way to do the above using awk?

Any help is hugely appreciated!

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for **exact** that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Hello Cyrus.  I had already provided the input. The one-line log

Comment: From where do you get `2900202469` in your output?

Comment: This is from the tag value. On the log above, the tag is 0, but on another log it's 2900202469. "tag 2900202469"

Comment: sed is not good at this. use awk.

Comment: Hello pynexj. But how can i take specific values on awk like I did above for sed? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggesting `awk` script:

```
 awk '{split($0,strArr,"\\( |\\), ");printf "%-10s %-12s %-9s %+16s -> %-16s %+6s -> %-6s %-8s %s\n",$9,$12,$14,$43,$44,$65,$67,strArr[2],$(NF-2)}' FS="( |, |: |->)" input.1.txt
```

#### Ouput from provided input:

```
 ingress    0            ORDERED       172.16.10.20 -> 172.16.0.10          21 -> 62040  ACK PSH  77
```